# How can I split an <xsl:foreach> into multiple parts?

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

I have a list of elements that I want to split into individual lists of 3.  The end result would be something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
</ul>
```

My XSLT is like this, but it doesn't work, because I can't insert `</ul>`, and I can't insert a less than sign (`<`).

```
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="$myroot/item">
        <li></li>

        <xsl:if test="position() mod $maxItemsPerColumn = 0">
            <!-- I want to close my ul, and start a new one here, but it doesn't work! -->
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might not be letting you close the UL inside of the loop since the UL started outside of the  loop.  Try moving it all inside of the for-each

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to do anything fancy like recursion.  And good lord, don't even contemplate using CDATA.

You just have to think like XSLT and ask:  "What input element do I want to transform into my output element?"

Assuming that each `ul` is supposed to contain N `item`s, you want to transform every Nth input `item`, starting with the first, into a `ul`:

```
<xsl:variable name="n" select="number(4)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <output>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/item[position() mod $n = 1]"/>
  </output>
</xsl:template>
```

Each of these `item` elements becomes a `ul` that contains the item and each of its N-1 following siblings:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $n]">
      <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Assuming an input document like this:

```
<root>
  <item>1</item>
  <item>2</item>
  <item>3</item>
  <item>4</item>
  <item>5</item>
  <item>6</item>
  <item>7</item>
  <item>8</item>
  <item>9</item>
</root>
```

...you get this output, if `$n` is set to 4:

```
<output>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>9</li>
  </ul>
</output>
```

Comment: @Robert Rossney: Nice one, clean and simple. +1

Comment: It actually is pretty simple, but there's a certain amount of XSLT you have to have ingested before it'll make a damn bit of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a recursive solution:

```
<xsl:call-template name="group">
  <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$myroot/item" />
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="group">
  <xsl:param name="items" />
  <xsl:if test="count($items) > 0">
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="$items[position() &lt;= 3]">
        <li>...</li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    <xsl:call-template name="group">
      <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > 3]" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

What this does is call the `group` template for the whole list of items. The `group` template writes out the first three elements of the list (or fewer if there aren't three) inside `<ul> ... </ul>` tags. Then it calls itself again with the rest of the list of items omitting the first three. When the list is empty, the `group` template does nothing.

XSLT is a very functional language, and following the rules (ie. not using `disable-output-escaping` for this) will save you from much pain and suffering in the future when you need to modify your templates again.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this (not tested, but you've got the idea )

```
(...)
<xsl:call-template name="recursive">
 <xsl:with-param name="root" select="$myroot"/>
 <xsl:with-param name="index" select="number(1)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
(...)


<xsl:template name="recursive">
<xsl:param name="root"/>
<xsl:param name="index"/>
<ul>
<li><xsl:value-of select="$root/item[$index]"/></li>
<li><xsl:value-of select="$root/item[$index +1 ]"/></li>
</ul>
<xsl:if test="$root/item[$index+2]">
<xsl:call-template name="recursive">
 <xsl:with-param name="root" select="$root"/>
 <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index+2"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</ul>]]></xsl:text>

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<ul>]]></xsl:text>
```

so in your case:

```
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="$myroot/item">
        <li></li>

        <xsl:if test="position() mod $maxItemsPerColumn = 0">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</ul>]]></xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<ul>]]></xsl:text>                
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's...horrifying.  Seriously, using *either* CDATA or `disable-output-escaping` in XSLT is generally a warning that you're making a conceptual mistake of some kind.  Using *both*?

Comment: I think you meant to say "this answer may be **harmful** to someone in the future" ;-)

Comment: At least we know it can be done this way, even though it may be the best approach.